# Draw several graphs in matplotlib, python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, draw

I need to draw graphs in python matplotlib.

For each graph I do some calculates before and then draw the graphe.
Here is some of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, verName):
    plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6]);
    plt.xlim(0,3500); #Axis x
    plt.ylim(0,100); #Axis y
    plt.plot(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, 'g');
    plt.scatter(LuxCoordinates, finalPix, linewidths=1)
    plt.grid(axis)
    plt.xlabel('X_Coordinates', color='r');
    plt.ylabel('Y_Coordinates', color='r');
    plt.title(verName, color='#afeeee');
    savefig(verName+'.png');
    plt.show();
```

My problem is that I call to this function twice or more, according to the number of graphs I have, I get the graphs in separate plots, but I want to draw all graphs on the same plot, in order to compare them.
How can I do it?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `plt.show()`

your function should get a `figure` or `axis` as an input parameter, and do the plotting on that figure, and then outside the function when you have done all the plotting you may call `plt.show()`

here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plotter ( ax, col ):
    data = np.random.normal( size=(50, 2 ) )
    x, y = data[:, 0], data[:, 1 ]
    ax.scatter( x, y, color=col )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6])

plotter( ax, 'Blue' )
plotter( ax, 'Red' )
fig.show( )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just remove plt.show() and put it after all calls to the draw function.